# Saving data to file or database

Tags: java, persistent-storage

I'm starting to work on a new Java desktop app that should help me and my colleagues learn vocabulary. It will contain around 700 words, some texts (that point to the words contained in them) and maybe some images (not sure about that part yet). The data will **never** change and I want the program to be able to run offline.

The question is: Should I use database, text file or serialize the data into file? Or perhaps if there is any other option I don't know about? If you could explain your choice in detail I would be glad.

Comment: Are you planning a web application, Android app, desktop app, or something else?

Comment: Oups forgot to mention that. It's a desktop app.

Comment: Then a regular database is off the table, unless you want to ship an installer which installs a database.  Maybe using a flat file would be the most expedient thing for you to do.

Comment: By flat file you mean text file or should I serialize the data into it? I can imagine it would be easier for me with serialization to create objects out of the words and then link them to the texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data never changes and is only 700 words it would probably be easiest to use a file.
If your data was a bit more complex and had many fields and was being constantly updated, a database would be more preferable but a csv file could still be used.

Comment: With such small entries, both methods will work extremely quick and efficiency isn't really a factor. But I would recommend .txt file or a .csv file where you can separate the words by a comma delimiter.

Comment: FWIW I prefer tab-delimited; they're much rarer in the kind of text you get in a "CSV" file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a word per line, so then you can loop through the file loading each line into a list of strings.

Comment: Problem with comma delimiter is that the texts are going to be normal articles so it is quite common to have commas in it.

Comment: Ahh okay, I thought when you said vocab you meant a dictionary of words, you can pick any delimiter that you want. So choose something that isn't within the text.

Comment: Or as @SteveSmith said, use tabs

Comment: There 2 types of data: 
1) Vocabulary
2) Texts that contain the vocabulary so that students can do gap filling etc.

Comment: You can load them into separate files? Or use two different delimiters, one for the separation of vocab and text and the other for separating unique instances of each.

Comment: 2 different files seem like a best option. Thanks for all the suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to access this data offline and data never changes, I think the best option would be to just use text file, which will be more efficient in terms of access and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the data in memory as Serializable Java objects, and store them serialized when your application is not running. Evaluate [airomem](https://github.com/airomem/airomem) - really nice solution that would perfectly work for you.